# comparing two strings (emails) and displaying matches

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and am running into an issue with getting data to display the way I'm hoping to.

I have two data sources - a directory containing all emails for the company, and a survey response from employees that have checked in this week.

What I'm trying to do is display the entire directory on the report (this part I can do), and have the employees that checked in be indicated by an "x" on a separate column.

A couple things to note if you need it:
Both datasources are strings and recognized as strings in crystal
Database Expert automatically links the email fields from both datasources.

Help with resolving this would be very appreciated!

The coding I've been trying is fairly basic -

If [directory_emails] = [survey_emails] THEN
"x"
Else
"o"

When I try to include this calculated field on the report, no data appears, where beforehand the directory data was appearing on the report.

what I'm expecting or trying to do is have some sort of indication that there was a match in the surveys email, and display an "x" in a separate column beside the full directory data.

Answer (score 0):

Use an OUTER JOIN from the Directory table to the Survey table to make sure all records from the Directory table are included in the report.

Use an IsNULL({survey.email}) to check if a directory email has a matching record in the Survey table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. These are two CSVs brought in via the ODBC - does SQL work in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Including a field from the other side of the join is causing Crystal to actually attempt the join. That join fails in your case, causing a no data result.

Your next step is to identify why your join is failing.  Are you sure you have at least some cases where the email addresses are IDENTICAL (upper/lower case, space padding, ...) on both sides of the join?

Comment: They are identical on both sides, checked spacing, formatting, everything. Since this is being brought in via python, I just ended up making changes to the python scripting before pulling in through the ODBC